# How to fix passing argument 1 of 'count' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to make a C language program with a linked list that uses recursion to count the total of the linked list nodes. However, I get this error:

```
passing argument 1 of 'count' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happen and how to fix it?

This is linked list node without recursion.  It works without error and gives return the value that I need.

```
int count(list_t *list){
    node_t *curr = list->head;
    int length=0;
    while(curr != NULL){
        length++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return(length);
}
```

And this one is recursive, but I get the "'count' from incompatible pointer" error.

```
int count(list_t *list){
    node_t *curr = list->currptr;
    int length=0;
    if(curr == NULL){
        return(0);
    }
    return(1 + count(curr->next));
}
```

This is structure of my linked list

```
typedef struct {
    int yyyy, mm,dd;
} date_t;

typedef struct {
    double balance;
} acc_balance;

typedef struct node node_t;

struct node{
    char *acc_no, *name, *lastname;
    date_t date;
    acc_balance acc_balance;
    node_t *next;
};

typedef struct {
    node_t *head;
    node_t *foot;
    node_t *currptr;
} list_t;
```

The output should be 8 but the program is terminated with:

`Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)  execution time : 5.093 s`

I'm still new to StackOverflow.  My apologies if I said something wrong.

Comment: It's exactly what the error says. Your function expects a `list_t *` and it looks like you're calling it with a `node_t *`.

Comment: I'm assuming `curr->next` is of type `node_t*` not `list_t*`? If so, you're mixing up node pointers and pointers to the wrapping list structure. Maybe just pass the head into the function have the program only operate on Nodes?

Comment: @Carcigenicate sorry for little information. i think i get what you mean sir, but still can't figure if i pass the head into function, its will update the list next time the function call itself?

Comment: Not exactly on the question asked, but on the code presented: recursion on a list _may_ be a bad idea. We often use dynamic data structures if we can'f reasonably predict their size (otherwise we could preallocate them within some static blocks of memory, which would make them more efficient). And you certainly don't want to run into a stack overflow if the list appears longer than you expected,  do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for posting the definitions.  That is very helpful.  For recursion, you only need to deal with the `node_t` and not the `list_t`.  It might look like this:

```
int count(node_t *curr)
{
    if (curr == NULL)
    {
        return (0);
    }
    return (1 + count(curr->next));
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
count(list->head);
```

If you want to be able to call it with a `list_t`, then add a helper function like this:

```
int countList(list_t *list)
{
    return count(list->head);
}
```

Comment: thanks you for the solution and explanation, i guess i mixed up `node_t` and `list_t`.

Comment: You are welcome!  That sort of mix up happens to everyone.  Don't worry about it.  If your issue is resolved, you should mark an answer as accepted so that is is clear to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different suggestion, if you want to have one function that handles both `list_t` and `node_t`:

```
int count(list_t *list, node_t *curr)
{
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        if (curr == NULL)
        {
            return (0);
        }
        return (1 + count(NULL, curr->next));
    }
    else
    {
        return count(NULL, list->head);
    }        
}
```

I don't like this way, but I'm trying to give you some options to consider.  I think my first answer, that just deals with `node_t` and not using `list_t` is the best solution.